# OAM 11g clear/remove custom application cookies

Tags: weblogic, single-sign-on

Does OAM support removing/clearing custom application cookies on log out ?

Oracle IDM version 11gR2PS3 (11.1.2.3.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, OAM doesn't support for custom application cookies on logout. The application needs to take care cookies cleanup during logout. However, you can configure OAM to invoke application logout during OAM logout by setting "[Logout Target URL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52734_01/oam/AIAAG/webgate.htm#AIAAG4877)" on WebGate profile.